# KDB How to join tables with different column names

Tags: join, kdb

If I have the following tables:

```
  t1:([] c1: 1 2 3; c2: 120 234 876)
  t2:([] cd1:1 2; d: 999 899)
```

How can I join tables where `t1.c1 = t2.cd2`, where `c1` and `cd2` are not linked columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to use a left join `lj` as follows:

```
q)t1: ([] c1: 1 2 3; c2: 120 234 876)
q)t2:([] cd1:1 2; d: 999 899)
q)t1 lj 1!`c1 xcol t2
c1 c2  d
----------
1  120 999
2  234 899
3  876
```

where we use `xcol` to rename the column `cd1` in `t2` to match `c1` in `t1`.

You can read more on joins at https://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/

Comment: Thanks for response..just checking my understanding. 1! Is rename first column of t2. Is it right?  And how it will work for two column join then?

Comment: 'xcol' renames column cd1 to c1.  1! will make first column as primary key which is c1 in this case. You could easily extend this to multi column joins. Read  about joins and left join for this specific case:  https://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#lj-ljf-left-join